# Looking for a window containing the solution of an equation

Tags: calculus, optimization, numerical-methods

I need to solve billions of times equations $\,f(x)=0\,$ with

$$f(x) := \sum_{i=1}^N \frac {z_i}{c_i + x}$$

All $z_i$ are positive and add to $1$. Among the $N$ coefficients $c_i$, $M$ are negative and $(N-M)$ are positive (they are such that $\;c_1 < c_2 <\cdots< c_M < 0\;$ and $\;1 < c_{M+1} < c_{M+2} < \cdots < c_N\;$).

The solution looked for is between $\,-c_{M+1}\,$ and $\,-c_M\,$. Since there are two infinite branches, the problem can be very poorly conditioned for a Newton method except if a small window containing the solution can be found.

Multiplying the function by the poles, that is to say solving $\,g(x)=0\,$ with

$$g(x) := (x + c_M) \cdot (x + c_{M+1}) \cdot f(x)$$

makes the problem better conditioned (asymptotes are removed) but the window is still too large.

Is there any way to reduce the interval which contains the solution ?

Any idea will be more than welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it with Maple by the fsolve command, not meeting any difficulties. See the Maple worksheet exported as [a PDF file](http://rapidshare.com/files/1619980487/fsolve3.pdf). I am waiting for your feedback.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I do not say that the problem is difficult per se since we know the window in which is the solution. The problem is related to numerical efficiency since these equations are to be solved billions of time. Even function g[x] is not very well conditioned for a use of Newton based methods. If I may ask, plot functions f[x] and g[x] between the two asymptotes. By the way, your z[i] do not seem to add to 1 (but this is a detail). Finally, I should precise that I would like to solve the problem in less that 4 iterations and a CPU time in the order of 0.001 second.